# Live preview in Xcode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Is there a way to preview my changes live in Xcode? For example, I have button that I moved 5 pixels to the right, and I want to see the result that I build my app to see the result on the simulator. Is it possible to view the changes without running the app every time?

Comment: Only Storyboard changes you can see in preview

Comment: You may also try Playground, all changes will be displayed right after you edit the code.

Comment: I agree. I see you're a new contributor so I'm not sure if you are new to iOS programming also. If so, please look into how to use auto layout (you can use it in Storyboards or code). You *really* want to (1) move by points not pixels and (2) code for multiple screen sizes. Right now there are *at least* 8 different ones and the rumors say that (at least) 2 more will be added in September.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: See Apple [docs](https://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/current/#/dev5d9411fd2)

---

Create a new playground and use a 'singleView' as your template. From there on you can see your changes live.

The good thing is that the template already has a label. You can either build on top of that or remove it and add your own views.

**Just make sure you click on View >> Assistant Editor >> Show Assistant Editor** otherwise you won't see the view.

[image]

---

If you want to make your changes in Xcode then you have to use `IBInspectable` & `IBDesignable` which require a bit more work. See this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yI-EY6MP9So) and [this](https://medium.com/@GeraldoBastos/whats-ibdesignable-ibinspectable-292829384e1) post

Answer (score 0):

you can see your storyboard changes by opening your Assistant Editor and then select preview, here you can select the device as well in which you want to see the changes.

but if you design you view by code then the only option is to run the code and see changes in the simulator or real device.